# How should we tag trigonometry questions?

Tags: discussion

I've noticed quite a few trigonometry questions on the main site in the past few weeks, and even asked one myself.  I found that the tags were a bit insufficient.  Is there a better way to narrow the search for trigonometry questions by utilizing certain existing tags, or should new specifiers be created?

Comment: Can you please show some examples?

Comment: You should explain by 'trigonometry' is not good enough...

Comment: Try to be more specific in the question. We are not mind-readers, so perhaps you should amend "should new specifiers be created" with a list of suggested tags?